# When developing Lightning Components, how do you get the component to refresh?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm developing a Quick Action Lightning Component that is delivered stand-alone, and I'm finding that it's hard to force the browser to refresh the component and ensure that the latest version is being rendered before I test a change.

I can't find any reference in the documentation on how to do this, but...

Can you force the refresh of a Lightning Component's source code when testing it?

If so - how?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Salesforce Setup, go to Security > Session Settings. In the Caching section, uncheck "Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance".

This is the right setting during development to make sure that the changes you make to your component take effect immediately and that you are not served a cached version of the component.

Comment: Worked first time.  You're a genius!

Answer (score 3):

If you do not have dependencies defined in the Application bundle then Lightning will not check for changes. In that case I found prior to Spring '17 it took 3 refreshes of the browser to get the updated version.

After Spring '17 I refresh the browser twice upon making changes when no dependency is defined.

If a dependency is defined then the browser will detect it and refresh automatically

Comment: Thanks for that - it may prove helpful, but I'm not using an app bundle - In this particular case I have a single component that is used in a quick action that I'm developing - so I'm not sure where I would define the dependency.

Comment: (question edited to reflect)

Comment: @RobBaillie you can't so u will have to refresh twice to be sure

Comment: :-)  URGH - so much to love ;-)

Comment: Yeah. Not sure if my way is correct or not but it works for me

Comment: I will try and then accept as answer if it works for me too...

Comment: refresh twice also works good for me, I did not find any real solution

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Chrome, there's an extension called [clear cache](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn?hl=en) that will do what you want. You click on it and it clears the cache so the latest version of your component will load when you refresh the page since it will no longer be in the cache. It also will automatically force a refresh of the page for you when you click on it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, though I'm finding that this isn't reliably refreshing the component.  Odd.

Comment: I'm surprised to hear that. It's what we were taught in the Salesforce University DEV-601 Lightning Components Training Course. It's always worked well for me. You can also clear the cache from the Dev Console using Chrome Developer Tools. Are you certain you've saved all the changes to your component before refreshing?

Comment: I'll add that as @Eric posted, it's always a good idea where possible to encapsulate your component within another component or component app bundle for testing.

Comment: 100%, yes it's being saved before navigating to the page. Tip on @Eric noted, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get it to always work on one refresh, but I have a way to always get it to refresh in two (better than nothing...).

For me, using Chrome:

1. Find Application tab in Dev Console
2. On the leftsidebar, find Storage -> IndexedDB. Expand it.
3. Right click ComponentDefStorage and select Refresh IndexedDB.
4. Refresh browser 2x